# LDAP server is not responding, unable to verify if this is an IPA server

Tags: centos, client, freeipa

Skip ipa.virtuora.co.in: LDAP server is not responding, unable to verify if this is an IPA server
Failed to verify that ipa.virtuora.co.in is an IPA Server.
This may mean that the remote server is not up or is not reachable due to network or firewall settings.
Please make sure the following ports are opened in the firewall settings:
TCP: 80, 88, 389
UDP: 88 (at least one of TCP/UDP ports 88 has to be open)
Also note that following ports are necessary for ipa-client working properly after enrollment:
TCP: 464
UDP: 464, 123 (if NTP enabled)
The ipa-client-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaclient-install.log for more information